# cinema project and object arrays

Tags: java

I've been trying to code a cinema project but I can't quite figure it out. When I run my program it only outputs the last value entered into the setAge so therefore allowing everyone before him into the cinema even if they aren't of the correct age. I believe it has something to do with the person object not being an array, but I'm not sure how to solve this, any ideas?

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Cinema 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        QueueWithArray q = new QueueWithArray();

        Person person = new Person();

        Scanner kybd = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Join (j), leave (l) or end (e)? ");
        String action = kybd.nextLine();
        while (!action.equalsIgnoreCase("e"))
        {
            if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("j"))
            {
                System.out.print("Enter your name: ");
                String name = kybd.nextLine();
                person.setName(name);
                q.add(name);
                System.out.println("What is your age? ");
                int age = kybd.nextInt();
                person.setAge(age);
                kybd.nextLine();

                System.out.println(name + " is going to the cinema and is " + age + " years old.");
            } 
            else if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("l"))
            {
                if (!q.isEmpty())
                {
                    if (person.getAge() >= 15 ) 
                    {
                        System.out.println(q.remove() + " has left the queue and entered the cinema");

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        System.out.println(q.remove() + " has left the queue, but is not old enough to watch the film");
                    }
                } 
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("Queue empty");
                }
            } 
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Invalid operation");
            }
            System.out.print("Join (j), leave (l) or end (e)? ");
            action = kybd.nextLine();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a second QueueWithArray that stores the ages of the people.

Imagine you have a pidgeonhole in which you can put a piece of paper with an age on it in. Every time you do p.setAge(age) you're taking the paper out of the pidgeon hole and putting a new piece in with the age specified.

When it comes to leave, you read the same piece of paper each time for each person. Instead, you want to have a queue of ages so that for each name you store an age.

Something like

```
System.out.print("Enter your name: ");
String name = kybd.nextLine();
System.out.println("What is your age? ");
int age = kybd.nextInt();
qName.add(name);
qAge.add(age);
kybd.nextLine();
```

or a better way to do it:

```
System.out.print("Enter your name: ");
String name = kybd.nextLine();
System.out.println("What is your age? ");
int age = kybd.nextInt();
Person person = new Person(name, age);
qPerson.add(person);
kybd.nextLine();
```

Comment: Hello, this is a good answer, but now that I've got the line Person person = new Person(name, age); it won't accept it, as it has parameters

Comment: You need to create a constructor for the person object that accepts parameters. So it would be like public Person(String name, int age){this.name = name; this.age = age;}

Comment: I've done this, but now its throwing an error saying that person can't be changed to string when I try and declare qPerson

Comment: That will be because you wrote QueueWithArray to only store Strings? Try adjusting it so that it can store persons instead

Comment: Or change and start using the default queue implementation instead https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html